# Extend base template in Smarty

Tags: templates, smarty

Is it possible to extend a base template with another template in Smarty?
I know this is possible in Django using the {% entend %} tag. Is there an equivalent (or workaround) in Smarty?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no build-in template inheritance in Smarty. But you can do similar thing with [`{include}`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.include.php) and [`{capture}`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.builtin.functions.php#language.function.capture).

Your page template can look like:

```
{capture assign="context"}
   <h2>Here is my page</h2>
   {... some other smarty suff here ...}
{/capture}

{assign var="title" value="Just simple title text here"}

{include file="base.tpl"}
```

And `base.tpl` can look like following:

```
<html>
   <title>{$title}</title>
   <body>
   {$context}
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Although this question is a bit old, I thought that maybe someone looking for this information as of august 2011 would benefit to know that this can be done now with Smarty 3.

Example With Inheritance

**layout.tpl**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{block name=title}Default Page Title{/block}</title>
</head>
<body>
{block name=body}{/block}
</body>
</html>
```

**mypage.tpl**

```
{extends file="layout.tpl"}
{block name=title}My Page Title{/block}
{block name=body}My HTML Page Body goes here{/block}
```

**output of mypage.tpl**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
My HTML Page Body goes here
</body>
</html>
```

Taken verbatim from: http://www.smarty.net/inheritance

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks for adding this answer! (I'm not using Smarty anymore, but as you say, it's a good reference for others)